# Error comparing files with bash script

Tags: bash

I have two txt files of this nature:

```
ENSG00000002587 
ENSG00000002746 
ENSG00000008300 
ENSG00000015413
```

When I try to compare them using the script

```
$ comm -23 <(sort file1.txt|uniq)> <(sort file2.txt|uniq)>
```

I get the following:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'
```

I have recently changed computers; this worked fine on my previous computer. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your command doesn't look right to me. Remove the `>`. The syntax for [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) is `<(command_list)`, not `<(command_list)>`.

Try:

```
comm -23 <(sort file1.txt|uniq) <(sort file2.txt|uniq)
```